# html2Canvas Issue on chrome

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

I am working on a small project which takes user input as photos,then convert the images to a collage.The project works fine on mozilla and safari,but at times it breaks on chrome.

Here are the steps I have taken to achieve it.

1. Using the uploaded files a html template is created and appended to
   DOM.
2. Using html2canvas library I convert the html template to
   canvas,obtain dataURL and send it to server.

Code snippet.

```
$(".upload-box" ).each(function(index,value) 
     {
      var image_src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
      var caption =  $(this).find("#caption > input").val();

      if(image_src && image_src.length)
      {
         var card_class = "pcard"+index;
         var card = '<div class="'+card_class+'">'+     
            '<div class="ptape">'+
            '<img src="'+tape_image+'" />'+  
            '</div>'+ 
            '<div class="pimg">'+
            '<img src="'+image_src+'" />  </div>'+
            '<div class="pcaption">'+caption+'</div>'+
            '</div>';

        $('.pholder').append(card);

        }

        });
```

The above part creates a template.

```
                html2canvas($(".pholder"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {

                var photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

               //make an ajax call to save photo

            }
        });
```

Responsible for converting the HTML template to canvas.

So the second part doesn't work in chrome most times,i.e the the rendering on canvas is not happening properly.But this works fine on mozilla and safari.

Strangely when I run execute this code on my local webserver it works fine on chrome too,but when run on production server it is not rendering on the canvas properly,but again this is purely a client side javascript and I can't figure out the reason for its failing.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No I couldn't figure out the solution just ended up taking the drastic step of making the collage on the server side.

Comment: Thats what I am afraid I will have to end up doing too.